# Handle click of custom dialog class with custom view from fragment or activity

Tags: android, interface, dialog

In custom dialog class with the custom view, I want to handle click of the button from Activity or fragment, I have created an interface for handling the button click but showing error.

> Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.ymcaspi.util.CustomDialog$DialogInterface.doLogin(com.ymcaspi.util.CustomDialog)' on a null object reference

My dialog class is

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog implements
    android.view.View.OnClickListener {
public Activity activity;
public Button btnYes, btnNo;
CustomDialog customDialog;
public CustomDialog(Activity activity) {
    super(activity);
    this.activity = activity;
}

DialogInterface dialogInterface;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.alert_login);
    btnYes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
    btnNo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_no);
    btnYes.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnNo.setOnClickListener(this);
}
//in custom adapter class i want to handle click of button from Activity or fragment, I have created a interface for handling button click
//but showing
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_yes:
            customDialog=new CustomDialog(activity);
            dialogInterface.doLogin(customDialog);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_no:
            dismiss();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    dismiss();
}



  public interface DialogInterface{
        void doLogin(CustomDialog dialog);

   }
}
```

i have implemented this interface in fragment but not working?

Comment: Apparently, your `dialogInterface` was never assigned, what did you intend to do with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: dialogInterface is null, you forgot to initialize it.

Comment: @Aaron i want to close dialog from activity when my task is done.

Comment: @farhana In that case, you could create a method `doLogin` in the same class without having an interface.

Comment: @Aaron i can but i want to call service from activity.then how can i do that?

Comment: my simple point is i want to call this dialog from activities and   thier button should be handle from activiyt.

Comment: @farhana I posted an example in my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one example that you can try if you intend to receive callback on your activity from the dialog:

```
class YourActivity extends Activity implements DialogInterface {

    void showDialog() {
        CustomDialog dialog = // init your CustomDialog
        dialog.setOnLoginClickListener(this);
        dialog.show();
    }

    void doLogin() {
        // Button yes has been clicked, do stuff... 
    }
}
```

And create a method to assign the listener in your `CustomDialog` class:

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {

    private DialogInterface dialogInterface;

    public void setOnLoginClickListener(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        this.dialogInterface = dialogInterface;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the concept from your code, I made a small change, your `setOnLoginClickListener`  giving me Dialog ref. so I passed the ref. of the interface in constructer. Actually I' was comparing `Activity` to Interface but i was confused.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't initialize **dialogInterface** on your dialog , if you've implemented the interface on your Activity , set your Activity to dialog interface

```
public CustomDialog(Activity activity,DialogInterface dialogInterface ) {
    super(activity);
    this.activity = activity;
    this.dialogInterface = dialogInterface ;
}
```

Comment: ... or pass an instance of `DialogInterface` to constructor or by setter

Comment: @AndreyBusik can explain properly.

Comment: i want to call service in `doLogin` after response wants to dismiss dialog.

Comment: @farhana : you have the instance of the dialog in your Activity , so after receiveing your response you can check the dialog is shown or not , then dismiss that.

Comment: @ArashGM i did this, showing incompatible type and I have also implemented the interface in fragment and activity too.

Comment: @ArashGM i made the small change which resolves the problem of incompatibility. thanks for answering.